# Wi-Fi troubles on Ubuntu 16.04, using Qualcomm Atheros in a Lenovo v510

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi

I have a Lenovo v510, running Ubuntu 16.04, and I can't get wireless networking to work. 
'Enable Wi-fi' has no effect, no networks show up. 
Some commands that I've tried, and their corresponding output below:

```
$ lspci  | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)
```

---

```
$ lsmod | grep ath
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           344064  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    28672  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              782336  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              602112  3 mac80211,ath,ath10k_core
```

---

```
$ dmesg | grep 02:00
[    0.581406] pci 0000:02:00.0: [10ec:8168] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.581425] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0xe000-0xe0ff]
[    0.581452] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xd1204000-0xd1204fff 64bit]
[    0.581470] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xd1200000-0xd1203fff 64bit]
[    0.581563] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.581564] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.581653] pci 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    1.438631] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168h/8111h at 0xffffbc8b4003d000, 54:ab:3a:e4:7d:ed, XID 14100800 IRQ 125
[    1.438632] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx    checksumming: ko]
[    1.454402] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth0
[    4.154735] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[   73.097799] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
```

---

```
$ rfkill list all:
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

How can I get my wireless network to work?

Comment: could you please see if you have `rfkill` and in case you do, show the output from `rfkill list all`

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I'll edit my question to include the output to rfkill list all.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that your wifi card is hard blocked "this is like a phisical lock that some cards have"

try

`sudo rfkill unblock all`

and let me know if the status from the hard block changes, if not it's probably a driver issue

Comment: Many thanks. The command unfortunately doesn't unblock the wifi, it is still hard blocked. How should I approach the driver issue? I'm already running 16.04 and update each time upon restarting.  I've also tried adding backports but this doesn't help much it seems.
Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Could you try this answer?... https://askubuntu.com/questions/380586/wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-wifi-doesnt-work-hard-blocked-yes

Comment: great :) if you like you can mark this as the answer to have the register of good answers about the topic :)